# XML attributes are not parsed in karaf

Tags: eclipse, jaxb, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

In karaf 4.0.3, XML attributes are not parsed via JAXB. The same application works with Eclipse internal OSGI container, but fails with karaf container.
JDK7 JAXB implementation is used in both cases.

Any ideas why it fails?

Incoming XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<responsible version="1.0">
</responsible>
```

Parse method:

```
public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    Activator.context = bundleContext;

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("===============================================");
                String name = "Responsible-response.xml";
                Class<com.log4j2test.pojo.Responsible> baseClass = com.log4j2test.pojo.Responsible.class;
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(baseClass);
                Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();
                final InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(name);
                final InputStream is2 = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(name);
                String incomingXml = convertStreamToString(is2);
                System.out.println("===Incoming XML: \n" + incomingXml);
                StreamSource source = new StreamSource(is);
                JAXBElement<?> unmarshaled = u.unmarshal(source, baseClass);
                Object po = unmarshaled.getValue();
                System.out.println("===Parsed POJO: " + po);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

The POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "responsible")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "responsible", propOrder = { "version" })

public class Responsible {
@XmlAttribute(name = "version")
protected Double version;

public Double getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(Double version) {
    this.version = version;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Responsible [");
    builder.append("version=");
    builder.append(version);
    builder.append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Output in KARAF:

[image]

Output in Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: Changing framework from quinox to felix solves the issue. Need to understand why it fails with equinox (karaf.framework=equinox).

Answer (score 1):

Adding  javax.xml.bind solved the problem:

```
karaf/etc/config.properties:
  org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation = \
    javax.xml.bind, \
```